# SQL Server XML field

Tags: sql, xml, query

I have an XML field in a database that stores the XML response from a service.

Every now and then, the service times out and what actually gets stored in the XML field is a non-XML value "Time out" which is just text.

What I'm wondering is how to query for that text!  If I try to just do a straight comparison, it tells me it cannot compare a string and an XML value - despite the value being stored is just text!!

Any thoughts on how I can query the text?  I'm frankly surprised that my procedure successfully stores text in an XML field.

Running in SSMS:

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[TransactionRequestID]
      ,[ResponseXML]
      ,[ResponseDate]
  FROM [TransactorData].[dbo].[tTransactionResponses]
where ResponseXML = 'Timeout Waiting for Reply'
```

ResponseXML is the XML field.

This results in:  Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The data types xml and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: I cannot get to pastebin from my work.  I tried where ResponseXML like '%time%' - same error.

Comment: I edited the question already.  We're hitting SQL 2016.  Not sure the exact version.

Comment: I was talking about to add the XML data content. Good luck though!